# Localization on a robot grid

Tags: localization

I have a skid steer drive train with an encoder on each side of the robot along with a gyro to measure the angle of the robot. The width of the robot is 26 inches. Using the encoders I would like to set up an x and y coordinate grid to know the pose of the robot and set up the system to go through waypoints to reach a destination. The robot has a starting reference point and I would like to go to another point in the area. Anybody have an idea of how to approach this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible approach:

1. Mapping
2. Localisation
3. Path planning (+ obstacle avoidance if there a need)

You can check out ROS (Robotic Operating System), which consists of many libraries and tools (including those for robot localization, mapping, path planning, etc.)
Here is the link: [ROS](http://ros.org)

Comment: Given his description  your solution  imho is an overkill

Answer (score 0):

If that's  all what  you have

1- write a kinematic model  of the robot

2- use any filtering  technique  to improve  your pose  estimate by using  the data from  gyro

That's  all  you can do with  encoders and a gyro

Answer (score 0):

Look up differential drive model. That will give you the basic equations to control the robot but generally speaking you will probably use the gyro to turn toward a specific target waypoint and encoders to drive to them. Don't try and use the encoders for the turn because skid steer robots will have a lot of slip. Also note that because you are basically dead reckoning you will drift over time. The best way to correct for that is to take readings that reference the environment.